# get MusicProperties/metadata of IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How can i get music properties of IsolatedStorageFile?
I am aware of `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` but i couldn't figure out how to get StorageFile from IsolatedStorageFile either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

> I couldn't figure out how to get StorageFile from IsolatedStorageFile either

To get a file from the applications local storage (WP7 Isolated Storage) you need to access the folder using:

```
StorageFolder localRoot = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await localRoot.getFileAsync("filename.txt");
```

> How can I get music properties of IsolatedStorageFile?

[Getting the properties of a file in the isolated storage is not supported by Silverlight.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) [Unfortunately it isn't supported with a StorageFile either.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getbasicpropertiesasync.aspx)